# Ansible ERROR! 'retries' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to run 2 times the playbook1 that may fail using import_playbook.

```
- name: Run playbook twice with potential failure
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook1.yml
  retries: 2
  delay: 10
  register: result
  until: result.rc == 0
```

However, there is no `retries/dely/register/until` attributes for import_playbook
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html

```
ERROR! 'retries' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude
```

Any alternatives or workaround ?

Comment: Such approach isn’t possible at that level, but on task level.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `import_playbook` module itself doesn't support the `retries`, `delay`, `register`, and `until` attributes as I know.

However, you can achieve a similar effect you want by incorporating a `loop` and error handling directly at your `playbook1.yml` level .
Here's an example I do quickly of how you might structure it:

```yaml
- name: Run playbook1 with potential failure
  hosts: <your_target_hosts>
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the playbook1
      include_tasks: playbook1.yml
      loop: "{{ range(2) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: retry_count
      register: result
      until: result.rc == 0
      retries: 2
      delay: 10
      when: result is failed
```

Here, the `include_tasks` module is used to include `playbook1`.yml, and a `loop` is added to run it twice `(range(2))`.

The `register` attribute captures the `result`, and the `until` attribute is used to retry if the result has a non-zero return code.

The retries and delay attributes control the retry behavior.

I hope this helps you to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I got error "ERROR! 'retries' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude" when I tried your workaround.